# Iterating through a foreach loop - only show 1 item rather than all

Tags: php, javascript

I've setup a Google map that has several plotted markers, each one when clicked on has a little popup with info within.

I'm using the following code to show the company name per plotted marker, but it's going through the foreach loop and showing **ALL** the company names within one popup.

How can loop through and show one company name per plotted marker? I need it to show the first company in the list on the first marker, the second company in the list on the second marker and so on.

```
// Setting the content of the InfoWindow
infowindow.setContent('
        <?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order')); foreach($pages as $post) { 
        setup_postdata($post); 
        $fields = get_fields(); ?>

        <p><?php echo $fields->company_name; ?></p> 

        <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
');
```

Comment: Rob, you edited your code back to worse and the mistake of the closing php tag inside the foreach is still there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code. what a mess! You would never have missed these obvious mistakes, if you would care to structure your code well! Don't write all your code on one line! Use best practice for code style!

Don't put all that PHP code inside the javascript function.
Instead, use a variable `$contentMarkup`, store everything in there and in the end echo this variable into the javascript code.

```
<?php
    $contentMarkup = '';
    //do all your stuff like
    $contentMarkup .= '<p>';
    $contentMarkup .= $fields->companyName;
    $contentMarkup .= '</p>';
?>

infowindow.setContent('<?php echo $contentMarkup; ?>');
```

Regarding your actual question: If you want to generate more than one tooltip/window/younameit, they have to have unique identifiers so you can create one for each company. But to say more I'd need to know a bit more about what exactly you're trying to do. What information is available and from what source.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Yes but you've removed code that makes the line function! It's in one line because there's PHP within a Javascript tag.

Comment: @Rob, just because the output of PHP needs to be on one line, doesn't mean that the PHP itself needs to be on one line.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question Markus.

Comment: @markus, my opinion on not being done with an answer is that you shouldn't post until you have something that reasonably resembles an answer. Posting a comment just so that you can get your foot in the door for "oldest answer" is misleading at best.

Comment: @zzzzBov It seems my not an answer has become the accepted answer. Sometimes showing some best practices is the better answer than giving some quick fix without explanation!

Answer (score 1):

show what you want based on `if` statement inside `foreach` loop

Comment: I'm not sure what are `$post`, `$pages` and `$fields` variables. What I meant was to check if item currently being checked in `foreach` loop is the one that you want to display. Besides, markus is right, there's a mistake in your php code, check your brackets in `foreach`